# get coordinates of places in Google Mp API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to extract the list of coordinates of places (polling stations) shown on a dynamic map using the Google API
http://psleci.nic.in/Default.aspx
After I have selected a particular State, district and AC, the map displays all corresponding places. 
My question is : how do I retrieve these places coordinates in a form of a table?
I've no knowledge of javascript, so I don't understand the associated scripts.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For getting the coordinates of different places, you can use [Geocoding Service in Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use to place markers or position the map.

It explains here what parameter you need to use, also it has a code example that can serve you as a guide.

For storing the coordinates or your data, you can check this documentation [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#creating-the-table), that has a tutorial about Populating the table.

Comment: Thank you Kendi. But my question was not about geocoding adresses. It was about extracting coordinates from an existing map which is not created by me.